# How to implement an InputStream that dynamically guesses the extension of a file that is streamed using Apache Tika?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I have a custom implementation of an `InputStream` that can currently update multiple `MessageDigest`-s and while reading the data. This allows for a single reading and processing of the data and avoids having to re-read files in order to calculate their checksums. This is quite efficient and saves time (and is implemented in [here](https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/blob/9dcb13255512cd396e63f712bb5ce82bb632726c/strongbox-storage/strongbox-storage-core/src/main/java/org/carlspring/strongbox/io/ArtifactInputStream.java)).

As a follow-up step, I would like to use Apache Tika to guess the file extension from the stream, which is sent over HTTP. I know some of you will suggest simply setting the `Content-Type` header and requiring that it's set, but, unfortunately, for various reasons, we cannot rely on this, or enforce it. Hence, I'm looking for a way to guess the extension based on the `InputStream`, while it's being sent.

We also need to be able to guess complex extension types (such as `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2` and other similar ones aren't easy to guess by just doing a substring from the last index of the dot until the end of the string).

What is the most-efficient way to do this? We cannot afford to read the whole files in memory, as the application will have to be able to handle a large number of concurrent requests. Could somebody please provide an example, of how this could be done?

Comment: Feed Apache Tika the first few kb of the file to detect with? It won't be able to do any container-based detection, but it should get you anything based on the file magic which is most of the common types

Comment: @Gagravarr: I've update the link to the source file.

Comment: @Gagravarr: If you're interested, could you maybe have a look at https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/pull/468/files#diff-8024b836036b6f5fb567a3ce48c2a4d6R221 and share your thoughts?

Comment: TBH I'd suggest you'd be better off posting to user@tika.apache.org to ask for review, many more Tika experts there! That said, I'd be tempted to pass the filename (if known) into Tika as a best-guess to help, and make sure you've got 8kb if possible!

Comment: @Gagravarr: How much is typically enough? Just 8KB, or are more needed?